# Get property of many list of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following object:

```
public class User {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public List<Language> Languages { get; set; }
  public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}

public class Language {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Skill {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have the following query:

```
List<UserModel> models = context.Users.Select(x =>
  new UserModel {
    Id = x.Id,
    Names = ????
  }).ToList();
```

I need to take:
1. The name of the first User Language, if any.
2. The names of the first 2 User Skills, if any.

And add those names to UserModel.Names where UserModel is:

```
public class UserModel {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public List<String> Names { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do this in my query?

Comment: Your `UserModel` class doesn't have a property for language - missed it out?

Comment: @DavidG The property Names in UserModel should get the Name of 1 User.Language and the Names of 2 User.Skills, if any ... I only need the names and place them in the UserModel.Names property.

Comment: And what if there are no languages? How do you know if the first item in `Names` is a language or a skill?

Comment: @DavidG I do not need to know ... This is just to display on UI and the names will be enough to distinguish between a Language and a Skill

Comment: Why your class `UserModel` mixes different things in the same list? You want to leave the first item out if there was no language or you want to put the skill-names there? Why dont you modify your `UserModel`, so that it has a property `string FirstLanguage` and `string FirstSkill` + `string SecondSkill`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Take` and `Concat`. Please try this code:

```
List<UserModel> models = context.Users.Select(x =>
  new UserModel {
    Id = x.Id,
    Names = x.Languages.Take(1).Select(y=>y.Name)
     .Concat(x.Skills.Take(2).Select(y => y.Name)).ToList()
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Languages and Skills are not of same type ... So how can you concat both?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Func<User, IEnumerable<string>> getUserLanguageNames = user => user.Languages.Select(language => language.Name);
 Func<User, IEnumerable<string>> getUserSkillNames = user => user.Skills.Select(skill => skill.Name);
 List<UserModel> models = context.Users.Select(user => new UserModel { Id = user.Id, Names = getUserLanguageNames(user).Concat(getUserSkillNames(user)).ToList() }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **take** and **skip** :

```
var ListUserModel = context.Users.Select(u => new UserModel { Id = u.Id, Names 
= new List<string> { u.Languages.FirstOrDefault().ToString(), 
u.Skills.Take(1).ToString(), u.Skills.Skip(1).Take(1).ToString() } });
```